# Flutter - Menu Vertical dentro de um bottomNavigaationBar

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou usando um `bottomNavigationBar` no meu App e a navegação está funcionando perfeitamente, contudo, em um dos itens(paginas) eu preciso ter um outro menu na porsição vertical(colunas) e ao clicar em um desses itens, estou usando o InkWell para isso, preciso que a pagina selecionada seja exibida dentro do body da pagina que contem o bottomNavigationBar.

Já tentei fazer de inúmeras maneiras. Usando setState, usando bloc,  mas nenhuma delas funcionou. Ou nada acontece ou a página selecionada é exibida com o fundo preto e sem a AppBar e o bottomNavigationBar.

Alguem poderia me ajudar a manter minha sanidade mental ?

antecipadamente agradeço

home.dart

```
import 'package:compesa_app/screens/contatos.dart';
import 'package:compesa_app/screens/menu.dart';
import 'package:compesa_app/screens/teste.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:compesa_app/screens/teste2.dart';
import 'package:compesa_app/blocs/menu_bloc.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = [
    Teste(),
    ContatosTab(),
    WorkPage(),
    Menu(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    MenuBloc bloc = MenuBloc();

    @override
    void dispose(){
      super.dispose();
      bloc.close();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Container(
          height: 25,
          child: Image.asset(
              "assets/images/Nova-Marca-Compesa-alternativa_branco.png"),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 64, 154),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<int>(
        stream: bloc,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Center(child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(snapshot.data));
        }
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 64, 154),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        buttonBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255,139,197,67),
        height: 50,
        items: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.multiline_chart, size: 20, color: Colors.white ),
          Icon(Icons.business, size: 20, color: Colors.white ),
          Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.clipboard, size: 20, color:  Colors.white),
          Icon(Icons.menu, size: 20, color: Colors.white ),
        ],
        animationDuration: Duration(
          milliseconds: 200
        ),
        index: 0,
        animationCurve: Curves.bounceInOut,
        onTap: (index){
          bloc.add(index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

menu.dart

```
import 'package:compesa_app/tiles/drawer_tile.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Menu extends StatelessWidget {
  PageController pageController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: ListView(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8), children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerTile(Icons.add_to_home_screen, "Registrar leitura",
                    pageController, 0),
                Divider(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 139, 197, 67),
                ),
                DrawerTile(Icons.headset_mic, "Reportar falta d´água",
                    pageController, 0),
                Divider(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 139, 197, 67),
                ),
                DrawerTile(
                    Icons.headset_mic, "Reportar vazamento", pageController, 0),
                Divider(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 139, 197, 67),
                ),
                DrawerTile(Icons.event_note, "Acompanhar protocolo",
                    pageController, 0),
                Divider(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 139, 197, 67),
                ),
                DrawerTile(Icons.calendar_today, "Calendário de abastecimento",
                    pageController, 0),
                Divider(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 139, 197, 67),
                ),
                DrawerTile(Icons.home, "Lojas físicas", pageController, 0),
                Divider(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 139, 197, 67),
                ),
                DrawerTile(Icons.contact_phone, "Contato", pageController, 0),
                Divider(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 139, 197, 67),
                ),
                DrawerTile(Icons.devices_other, "Registrar leitura",
                    pageController, 0),
              ]),
        ),
      ])),
    );
  }
}
```

drawer_tile.dart

```
import 'package:compesa_app/blocs/menu_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DrawerTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final IconData icon;
  final String text;
  final PageController controller;
  final int page;

  DrawerTile(this.icon, this.text, this.controller ,this.page);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){ 
          bloc.add(page);
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 60.0,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(icon,
              size: 32.0,
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 64, 154), //Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 64, 154),
              
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 25.0,),
              Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  //color: Color.fromARGB(255,139,197,67), //Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 64, 154),
                ),
                )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

menu_bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

class MenuBloc extends Bloc<int, int>{
  @override
  get initialState => 0;

  @override
  Stream<int> mapEventToState(int event)async*{
    if (event == null ) {
      event = 0;
    }
    yield event;
  }
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Por favor, clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/427334/edit) e traduza a pergunta.

Comment: Pergunta traduzida. Obrigado.

Comment: Uma dica: Na tela que você for fazer o menu vertical, coloque uma `TabView` onde cada aba será uma tela desse menu vertical. Assim seu `BottomNavigator` pode continuar da maneira que está, você terá apenas que mudar a aba visível ao clicar em um item do menu vertical. Se eu conseguir um tempo hoje, coloco aqui uma resposta detalhada.

Comment: Obrigado Matheus, funcionou.